# Error while create setup.msi using setup and deployment in vb.net 2015

Tags: vb.net

What happen with my vb.net program error while build setup.msi like in the following picture

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I can't see any error in the picture. What is the problem?

Comment: Vb.net not responding while processing setup.msi. i have try to reinstall .net framework, and repair installed update of ms visual studio, but still happen, vb.net going not responding while build setup.msi.  sorry in this post i dont tell about vb.net not responding

Comment: New update from me, while vb.net going not responding, windows installer showing error "install server not responding" retry or cancel button. I think that happen because windows installer service error, maybe. I will try again tomorrow, and update here again

Comment: I have found the solution of my problem, i re install vs.net 2015 program(uninstall, clean temporary file and registry using ccleaner and then install vs.net 2015 again). And my problem solved. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution of my problem, i re install vs.net 2015 program

1. uninstall vs.net 2015
2. clean temporary file and registry using ccleaner
3. install vs.net 2015 again

And my problem solved, build setup.msi running properly now. :-)

Thanks for any respond

Regards :-)